# jQuery ui dialog box always positioned to top left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

My jquery UI dialog box always gets positioned to top left no matter what I specify in the position attribute. I tried adding a css position to the div too. But it was of no use.
Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

```
$("<div>----Play again?---</div>").dialog({
                    title: 'Game Over!',
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: 'auto',
                    autoOpen: false,
                    draggable: true,
                    modal: false,
                    position: 'center',
                    buttons:{ 
                        "Yes": function() {
                        startGame();
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        "No": function() {
                        alert('\nYour Score is: '+score+'\nGood Bye '+playerName+'!');
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Pass it an object as documented; `{ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }`

Comment: I think that if you were to remove the position attribute you would find it centres by itself

Comment: [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) said default position is at center, default setting is `{ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }`. So remove position attribute from options of dialog and try'

Comment: @AlexK., Bhushan Kawadkar: I have tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: @TusharRaj: I have tried that as well. The reason I added the position attribute was because the dialog was not centered by itself

Comment: Could it be a problem with the libraries I have included. I have included the below libraries for jquery, jquery-ui and jquery-ui css.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you shouldnt need to set a position:

```
$("#dialog").dialog();
```

[should centre by default](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default).

I did have a look at the article, and also checked what it says on the [official jquery-ui site about positioning a dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position) : and in it were discussed 2 states of: initialise and after initialise.

**Code examples - (taken from jQuery UI 2009-12-03)**

Initialize a dialog with the position option specified.

```
$('.selector').dialog({ position: 'top' });
```

Get or set the position option, after init.

```
//getter
var position = $('.selector').dialog('option', 'position');
//setter
$('.selector').dialog('option', 'position', 'top');
```

I think that if you were to remove the position attribute you would find it centres by itself else try the second setter option where you define 3 elements of "option" "position" and "center".